# How to put current method's parameter into a list

Tags: java, variadic-functions

I have two methods like

```
public void login(String userName, String password)
{

}

public void login(String userName, String password, Object loginOption)
{

}
```

and I hope to get all of them soloved in a certain method:

```
public boolean getThingsDone(Object...vargs)
{
    //Do The Real Action
    return true;
}
```

so I have to make different function call:

```
public void login(String userName, String password)
{
    getThingsDone(userName,password);
}

public void login(String userName, String password, Object loginOption)
{
    getThingsDone(userName,password,loginOption);
}
```

Is there any way that I can put different parameter into one List, so I can make the same call

```
getThingsDone(parameterList);
```

I have no idea but declare both method into login(String ...vargs), but that will confuse other people use this method.

Is there any one ever meet this problem? Any hint would be appreciated.

Comment: I think that is a bad idea to use varargs for this. What is wrong calling login(String, String) from login(String, String, Object)?

Comment: @threenplusone I agree this is a bad idea, but I would do it the other way around: call login(String, String, Object) from login(String, String). The logic is then needed only in one method and the other methods just provide default parameters.

Comment: Yes, I will modify the login() method like this. But still there are some methods have no relationship with login(), and they also want to use the getThingsDone() method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a `Login` class with three attributes: - `username, password, loginOption`.

```
public class Login {
    private String username;
    private String password;
    private Object loginOptions;

    // Constructors
    // public accessors.
}
```

And in your login method pass `Login` reference as parameter: -

```
public void login(Login login) {

}
```

So, if you want to pass `loginOptions`, call it like this: -

```
login(new Login(username, password, loginOptions));
```

else, just use a `2-parameterized constructor` of `Login` class: -

```
login(new Login(username, password));
```

And from login method, call other method like this: -

```
getThingsDone(login);
```

Now in that method, check : - `if (login.getLoginOptions() != null)`. If it is null, then do things related to `username` and `password`. And if it is not null, then do things related to all of them.

Comment: That's a good idea, In this condition the class 'Login' can describe the parameter information when other people use this. But sadly  getThingsDone() is a 'magic' method and will be used also in resetPassword(String,String) etc. It's too hard to define a new class for each method.

Comment: @abuuu.. You don't need to create another class for that method. In resetPassword also pass the same parameter - `Login`. `resetPassword(Login login)`. And from there call your `getThingsDone` the same way. So, you have encapsulated your login information in an object. And everywhere, you can pass that object, and manipulate it.

Comment: Oh, that means I only need to create a 'parameterClass' for this whole class, and to pass different parameters as parameterClass's property. Thanks, I will try it immediately.

Comment: @abuuu.. Exactly. That would make you job easier. And it's more `Object Oriented`.

Answer (score 3):

```
public void login(String userName, String password, Object loginOption)
```

This method should do the thing and should be able to handle the situation when `loginOption` is null.

Then you could invoke it as follows:

```
public void login(String userName, String password) {
    login(userName, password, null);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass an array list and use the length to do what ever you need. Why not use overloaded methods and modularize the rest of the code?